# Automatically map CLOB type to string using sqoop

Tags: apache, sqoop

I've been working with sqoop and so far I've encountered a problem regarding CLOB type which was not solved automatically.

My workaround consist to set this `--map-column-java "$MAPPING_PARAM"` where mapping param is taken automatically from another source and it's something like `Col_name=String`.

This looks bad because i need to specify every single column to `sqoop`, which is not really nice.

Is there any way to tell sqoop to automatically treat all the possible `CLOB type` to String?

Comment: There is no alternate solution yet for this yet. For now, you have to do like this only.

Comment: Before sqoop import do a sqoop eval and fetch the clob columnames .Then  build a string like --map-column-java Col1=String,col2=String dynalically and append this at end of sqoop import. Entire thing can be easily done using shell script

Comment: @vinayak_narune yes, in fact im already using a shell script for that. I was wandering if there is a way to avoid this and simply tell sqoop to map all the clob as string.

Comment: @ennon to best of my knowledge NO.

Comment: @vinayak_narune lol, thank you i figured it out time ago that this feature has not been implemented yet. What a pity..